# Javascript get local file path via a dialog

Tags: javascript, file, local, electron

I'm writing a database application in node.js via electron. The user needs to be able to select a json file from anywhere on their system, and I need to get the path or in some other way copy it to the program directory. I've tried a variety of different methods but the only thing that even makes a dialog is `<input type="file">`, but that returns a path with `fakepath` in it (I believe this is for browser security, but I don't need that since again, electron app). Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yes it's a security implemented by all browsers.
If you really need to pass by input type file, 
you can use SSL to ask a user intervention to obtain the real path

Comment: I need to get the path in some way. Any idea how I would implement that in electron?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. The documents are talking about getting the user to select a local file and then doing some slicing to get things into the client side. It's just a thought I saw these docs and thought maybe it has a fighting chance.

Comment: Instead of writing a file on the client there is an alternative to use client side storage perhaps:http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/index.html

Comment: I can see you added "electron" to the post tags, you can do this simply using NodeJS FS package! Need me to show you how ?

Comment: I'd appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [dialog.showOpenDialog](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) api.

> **dialog.showOpenDialog([browserWindow, ]options[, callback])**
>
> - browserWindow BrowserWindow (optional)
> - options Object
>
>   - title String
>   - defaultPath String
>   - filters Array
>   - properties Array - Contains which features the dialog should use, can contain openFile, openDirectory, multiSelections and createDirectory
> - callback Function (optional)

**Example**

```
const dialog = require('electron').dialog;
console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: [ 'openFile', 'openDirectory', 'multiSelections' ]}));
```

Comment: Hi, this seems perfect, but unfortunately, no matter how I do it, `electron.dialog` is undefined. I copied and pasted the example you gave into a script, is there something else I should do/know? Thanks

Comment: This is copied right from their documentation, I have used it before. Make sure you're using the right version of electron `electron --version`

Comment: Still can't quite get it to work, but I'll accept it because I'm relatively new to electron and I'm sure it's my error. I'll play around with it some more, thanks.

Comment: @IgorT. Yes, after playing with the electron modules a little I was able to use this answer.